# Unknown Styling on Header

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On [my website](http://echomartin.com/angie-wiechmann/blog/), I have 80 pixels of margin showing up between my header and my menu. This isn't a problem on the front page, only on the blog, which uses the standard site header.

When I inspect it with Google, it says that this is element styling on the div with the class custom-header, not part of the CSS. I'm using a child theme of WordPress Twenty Seventeen. I've looked through the CSS and I don't see where it says to add a margin. I looked through the header-image.php and haven't found anything. Note that the margin underneath the header image goes away on mobile view. Here's what I have for CSS/HTML in both the child and Twenty Seventeen:

**Child Theme CSS:**

```
/*  Front Page: Header  */
.has-header-image .custom-header-media img,
.has-header-video .custom-header-media video,
.has-header-video .custom-header-media iframe {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    max-width: 1000%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100vw; /* vw prevents 1px gap on left that 100% has */
    width: auto;
    top: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 1px; /* Prevent header from extending beyond the footer */
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .site-branding,
.has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .site-branding,
.has-header-image.home.blog .site-branding,
.has-header-video.home.sblog .site-branding {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .site-branding,
.has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .site-branding,
.has-header-image.home.blog .site-branding,
.has-header-video.home.blog .site-branding {
    top: 40px;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

body.has-header-image .site-title,
body.has-header-video .site-title,
body.has-header-image .site-title a,
body.has-header-video .site-title a {
    color: #0F0566;
}

body.has-header-image .site-description,
body.has-header-video .site-description {
    color: #2EE6D5;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.site-title {
    font-family: Lato;
    color: #0F0566;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-transform: none;
}

.site-description {
    font-family: Lato;
    color: #0F0566;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70vh;
    display: block;
    left: 50vw;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
}

    /* Scroll down arrow */

    .site-header .menu-scroll-down {
        display: block;
        padding: 1em;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .site-header .menu-scroll-down .icon {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    .site-header .menu-scroll-down {
        color: #fff;
        top: 1em;
    }

    .site-header .navigation-top .menu-scroll-down {
        color: #767676;
        top: 0.7em;
    }

    .menu-scroll-down:focus {
        outline: thin dotted;
    }

    .menu-scroll-down .icon {
        height: 50px;
        width: 40px;
    }

/*  Blog Header */

body.has-header-image:not(.twentyseventeen-front-page):not(.home) .site-title,
body.has-header-video:not(.twentyseventeen-front-page):not(.home) .site-title,
body.has-header-image:not(.twentyseventeen-front-page):not(.home) .site-title a,
body.has-header-video:not(.twentyseventeen-front-page):not(.home) .site-title a {
    color: #2EE6D5;
}

.has-header-image:not(.twentyseventeen-front-page):not(.home) .custom-header {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.has-header-image:not(.twentyseventeen-front-page):not(.home) .site-description {
    display: none;
}
```

**Twenty Seventeen CSS:**

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
13.1 Header
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#masthead .wrap {
    position: relative;
}

.site-header {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    position: relative;
}

/* Site branding */

.site-branding {
    padding: 1em 0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: margin-bottom 0.2s;
    transition: margin-bottom 0.2s;
    z-index: 3;
}

.site-branding a {
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.site-branding a:hover,
.site-branding a:focus {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.site-title {
    clear: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 1.25;
    letter-spacing: 0.08em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.site-title,
.site-title a {
    color: #222;
    opacity: 1; /* Prevent opacity from changing during selective refreshes in the customize preview */
}

body.has-header-image .site-title,
body.has-header-video .site-title,
body.has-header-image .site-title a,
body.has-header-video .site-title a {
    color: #fff;
}

.site-description {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-size: 0.8125rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

body.has-header-image .site-description,
body.has-header-video .site-description {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.custom-logo-link {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto;
}

.custom-logo-link img {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 80px;
    width: auto;
}

body.home.title-tagline-hidden.has-header-image .custom-logo-link img,
body.home.title-tagline-hidden.has-header-video .custom-logo-link img {
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.custom-logo-link a:hover,
.custom-logo-link a:focus {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

body:not(.title-tagline-hidden) .site-branding-text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.custom-header {
    position: relative;
}

.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header,
.has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .custom-header,
.has-header-image.home.blog .custom-header,
.has-header-video.home.blog .custom-header {
    display: table;
    height: 300px;
    height: 75vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.custom-header-media {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.custom-header-media:before {
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,000000+100&0+0,0.3+75 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#00000000", endColorstr="#4d000000", GradientType=0); /* IE6-9 */
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.has-header-image .custom-header-media img,
.has-header-video .custom-header-media video,
.has-header-video .custom-header-media iframe {
    position: fixed;
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    max-width: 1000%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100vw; /* vw prevents 1px gap on left that 100% has */
    width: auto;
    top: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 1px; /* Prevent header from extending beyond the footer */
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.wp-custom-header .wp-custom-header-video-button { /* Specificity prevents .color-dark button overrides */
    background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    height: 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, border-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    width: 45px;
}

.wp-custom-header .wp-custom-header-video-button:hover,
.wp-custom-header .wp-custom-header-video-button:focus { /* Specificity prevents .color-dark button overrides */
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8);
    color: #fff;
}

.admin-bar .wp-custom-header-video-button {
    top: 62px;
}

.has-header-image:not(.twentyseventeen-front-page):not(.home) .custom-header-media img {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
}

/* For browsers that support 'object-fit' */
@supports ( object-fit: cover ) {
    .has-header-image .custom-header-media img,
    .has-header-video .custom-header-media video,
    .has-header-video .custom-header-media iframe,
    .has-header-image:not(.twentyseventeen-front-page):not(.home) .custom-header-media img {
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        -o-object-fit: cover;
        object-fit: cover;
        top: 0;
        -ms-transform: none;
        -moz-transform: none;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* Hides div in Customizer preview when header images or videos change. */

body:not(.has-header-image):not(.has-header-video) .custom-header-media {
    display: none;
}

.has-header-image.twentyseventeen-front-page .site-branding,
.has-header-video.twentyseventeen-front-page .site-branding,
.has-header-image.home.blog .site-branding,
.has-header-video.home.blog .site-branding {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

**header-image.php HTML:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Displays header media
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

?>
<div class="custom-header">

        <div class="custom-header-media">
            <?php the_custom_header_markup(); ?>
        </div>

    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/site', 'branding' ); ?>

</div><!-- .custom-header -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the style is in a separate file. This should fix your issue:

```
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .blog .custom-header {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Maybe you have to use `margin-bottom: 0; !important`

Comment: That solved it! I tried a couple variations of that without success, so I'm not sure what I was doing wrong. Thank you!